# Populate a Multi-select checkboxes programatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the below multiselect checkbox code. When the user visits this page, i need to get the data
from the db and populate the checkboxes according to it. I get the data in the forma of an array.

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="alot">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">

       <div style="font-weight: bold" id="checkBoxes">Business Units:</div>

       <input type="checkbox" value="All" class="checkBoxClass" id="ckbCheckAll" />
       <label for="ckbCheckAll">All</label> 

       <input type="checkbox" value="29" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox1" />
       <label for="Checkbox1">XYZ</label> 

       <input type="checkbox" value="30" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox2" />
       <label for="Checkbox2">ABC</label>

     </fieldset>
   </div>
```

Below code is not working.

```
$("#alot").val(array);
$("#alot").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

array contains values like [29,30]

Am i missing anything ?

Comment: `.val()` is available only for form elements (`input`s, `textarea`s, `select`s, `options`s, not for `div`s... And what is `.checkboxradio("refresh")`? A plugin of yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check each `<input>` based on whether it's value is found in your array:

```
var arr = ['All', 30]

$('#alot').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', function(){
    var value = Number(this.value) || this.value;
    return $.inArray(value, arr) > -1; 
}).checkboxradio('refresh');
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xy6voyar/)

Comment: Thanks George. Its working now!!